# How to reference the inflated view elements?

Tags: android, android-inflate

I need some help on this. I'm inflating a view. The view is basically a card view with a spinner in it.

The view is inflated on a button click like this:

```
itineraryDetailLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.itineraryDetailLinearlayout);
View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
itineraryDetailLL.addView(childView);
```

Now the problem is that whenever I click the spinner in the first inflated card view it works fine but on clicking on the spinner in the second inflated view it gives me the following error:

```
09-11 10:54:44.976 31698-31698/com.application.marketvisit E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
09-11 10:54:44.976 31698-31698/com.application.marketvisit E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
09-11 10:54:44.986 31698-31698/com.application.marketvisit E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Filter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.Filter$FilterListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performFiltering(AutoCompleteTextView.java:861)
                                                                                   at com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner.onFocusChanged(MaterialBetterSpinner.java:49)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4962)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:7678)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7657)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7624)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7603)
                                                                                   at com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner.onTouchEvent(MaterialBetterSpinner.java:74)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.
09-11 10:54:44.988 31698-31698/com.application.marketvisit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.application.marketvisit, PID: 31698
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Filter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.Filter$FilterListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performFiltering(AutoCompleteTextView.java:861)
                                                                                 at com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner.onFocusChanged(MaterialBetterSpinner.java:49)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4962)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:7678)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7657)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7624)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7603)
                                                                                 at com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner.onTouchEvent(MaterialBetterSpinner.java:74)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java
```

This is the cardview.xml that I'm inflating:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp">

<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
                android:id="@+id/zonePlanItineraryspinner"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Select a Zone"
                app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
                android:layout_below="@id/deletePlanItinerary"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: `View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardview, itineraryDetailLL);` will inflate and attach to the layout in one step. Additionally, providing the parent during inflation also lets Android pick the correct type for the initial layout params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as possible, don't use multiple IDs in one layout, Android only detects one, hence the `null object reference` in your stack trace.

According to the API guides:

> An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be
>   unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often
>   be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when
>   possible).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id

**EDIT**

Since you're inflating new layouts with the same IDs, try the following:

```
View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
MaterialBetterSpinner spnr = childView.findViewById(R.id.zonePlanItineraryspinner);
spnr.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // New CardView layout spinner code goes here...
    } 
});
```

You should use the newly inflated layout to find the views by ID.

Comment: I've done the same thing. First I've referenced the spinner using `findViewById` and then I've set the adapter and then called the `setOnItemClickListener`. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: This was so simple! Now I know what I was doing wrong. I was looking for spinner in the whole view instead of in the view that I've inflated. Thankyou so much!